# Would the 6th level Shepherd Druid's Mighty Summoner feature works on summoned creatures not made from spells

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, druid, multi-classing, summoning

To clarify, when I say "summoned creatures not made from spells", I mean summons that are from class features and the like, so the Shadow Sorcerer's Hound of Ill Omen, the Hexblade's Accursed Specter, Raven Queen's Sentinel Raven (tho less hp on this would be nice) and the Beastmaster/Drakewarden's Animal/Drake Companion. Sinces these are features that summon creatures, would they work with the Shepherd Druid's Mighty Summoner if they aren't technically spells?

Comment: Probably worth mentioning that the latter two are UA (unless the Raven Queen has been published without me catching it), mostly I suppose should they ever be published with significant changes, this question doesn't become confusing on that front.

Answer (score 10):

### Mighty summoner does not apply to non-spell summonings

The relevant line from the class feature (XGtE, p. 24; emphasis added):

> Any beast or fey summoned or created by *a spell* that you cast gains the following benefits:

The feature is missing any clause, such as "... or other feature/magic" which would have the effects apply to creatures summoned by features.

---

As a side note on the listed examples; Hound of Ill Omen would not work because it is also a monstrosity, the Accursed Specter is undead, and the Drakewarden is a dragon.