# Does the Shepherd Druid's Mighty Summoner feature apply to creatures summoned through their Faithful Summons feature?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, druid, summoning

Mighty Summoner says (emphasis mine):

> Any beast or fey summoned or created *by a spell that you cast* gains the following benefits: [...]

Faithful Summons says (emphasis mine):

> If you are reduced to 0 hit points or are incapacitated against your will, you can immediately gain the benefits of conjure animals *as if it were cast using a 9th-level spell slot*.

Does the phrase "as if it were cast using a 9th-level spell slot" indicate that we should treat this as if we are casting the spell, thereby allowing us to apply Mighty Summoner to the creatures summoned?

Note, this question is different from this Q&A, as it is unclear if Faithful Summons counts as casting a spell: [Would the 6th level Shepherd Druid's Mighty Summoner feature works on summoned creatures not made from spells](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/177200/would-the-6th-level-shepherd-druids-mighty-summoner-feature-works-on-summoned-c)

Comment: Other questions asking about the use of "as if": "[Does using an Animated Shield count as 'wielding a shield' for Unarmored Defense?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/77539)" and "[Can you maintain concentration on non-spell abilities (that require it) while raging?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/167841)"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Yes, in both rules and (very likely) intent as well

Intent wise; since normal summons attacks count as magical it makes little sense for your higher level features to neglect this and be weaker than your usual summons, and most classes are designed with some kind of synergy in mind. There is no doubt in my mind that the intention of this feature is to benefit from Mighty Summoner.

Rules wise; if it were cast with a 9th level slot it would benefit from Mighty Summoner, so it does what it says on the tin. It has to be cast by 'you' otherwise you wouldn't get the benefits of the spell as it suggests (control etc), so it can't be that 'other entity' casts it on your behalf.

Answer (score 1):

No, Mighty Summoner would not affect those summons in this case.

Mighty Summoner is clear that it only affects fey or animals that were summoned/conjured by spells you cast, and the important distinction is that you never actually cast the spell Conjure Animals through the Faithful Summons feature. You gain the benefits of it **as if** it were cast at 9th level, which is likely only included to define the amount of creatures conjured. Even if you take it to mean that the spell is cast, it doesn't say **you** cast the spell and would therefore not satisfy the conditions for Mighty Summoner.

For reference, [this other question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/169477/do-class-or-subclass-features-that-relate-to-spellcasting-apply-when-producing-a)'s accepted answer details the specifics on class features interacting with similar effects.

Comment: The referenced question is about 'produce the effect' and this is about 'as if it were cast' which are both very different.